# RVIZ not showing PointCloud2

Tags: kinect, rviz, openni-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have an issue using RVIZ when I try to visualize my data coming from Kinect using the following:

$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.launch

$ rosrun rviz rviz

[C:\fakepath\Screenshot-13.png](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/338/screenshotaeie.png/)

nothing shows up, the only thing that is shown is the sensor_msgs/Image topics (little image frame in the right), why is that happening? I get no errors, but I can't see anything.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34383/rviz-not-showing-pointcloud2/) by [DavidLavy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2177/davidlavy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2012-05-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-20**:
Which version of rviz are you running, Electric, Fuerte, Diamondback? Are you sure the point cloud is within the viewing area of the display?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-05-20**:
Isn't there some nodelet you need to convert opennI data to PointCloud2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the 3D viewing window in rviz isn't working properly, or the pointcloud isn't within your field of view.

I would try rotating the view to see if your pointcloud is somewhere else, and I would check that your graphics drivers are installed properly. See: http://ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting

Note that rviz has fairly high graphics requirements, and doesn't usually work when run on an integrated chipset or within a virtual machine.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0